# How to Register Permanent User-Defined-Functions (UDFs) in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

with sqlContext we can register a UDF like this: `sqlContext.udf.register("sample_fn", sample_fn _ )`
But this UDF is limited to that particular sqlContext only. I wish to make the registration persistent, so that I can access the same UDF in any subsequent sqlcontext.
Or is there any other way to register UDFs in sparkSQL so that they remain persistent?

Comment: What about register it into hive and then use it from Spark? Or you can write functions and add it as --jars into your project?